# Why the Haar measure on $F^\times$?

Tags: measure-theory, terminology, lebesgue-measure

Given a Haar measure $dx$ on a field $F$, we always take the Haar measure $d^\times x = dx/|x|$ on its multiplicative group $F^\times$. Is there a good reason to do so, and not for instance to conserve the measure $dx$?

Can you provide some references for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply because $dx$ is no more an invariant measure for the multiplication. Indeed, $d(nx)=|n|dx$ (this is the usual change of variables rules, where $|n|$ is the jacobian determinant of $x \mapsto nx$), so you want to get rid of this multiplicative factor to get the sought invariance.